# async method reducing the coverage under branches

Tags: javascript, babeljs, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

Here's my code:

```
it('test method', async () => {
    const self = {}
    const a = await identityModule.init(self);
    expect(a).to.equal("abc")
  });
```

[image]
Note that the coverage is 100% under branches.

However, when I change the method to `async`, it reduces the coverage under branches. And I don't see any conditions and branching. So unable to figure out.

Also, note that line # 2 gets unusually invoked to 122x in that case.

[image]

I believe this started happening since I configured `.babelrc` to Trans compile some of the files.